# OAuth google login redirect to specific url

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-signin

Hi,

I have a web api 2.0 and a number of apps that make use of that api.
I'm trying to implement google authentication like so: from the app I make an http call to the api to retrieve all the external logins like so`return $http.get(apiRootAddress + "Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true");` everything works great I get the url I need and I set the window location to the url i just recieved: */api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=localhost%3A62556%2Fsignin-google&state=...* but it get's redirected to the api address, not the redirect that I need. How can I set the redirect url in here: Account/ExternalLogins?**returnUrl=%2F**&generateState=true to a desired one? I have tried different encoded urls but I get "invalid_request" :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try http://localhost/ so encoded in your case: http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A62556

it should work with localhost, its also in the documentation, i just think u missed the http:// there. check https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app.

Comment: Hi , i made a get request to http://localhost:57792/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A62556&generateState=true" i received the url: http://localhost:57792/api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=Google&response_type=token&client_id=self&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A62556%2F when i call it i get invalid request

Comment: is there a message provided in the invalid request? u changed ur ip?

Comment: nope this it the text response in fiddler:  error: invalid_request

Comment: i don't think it can be done if my api is on port 57792 i can not redirect to port 67792 when getting the token from google Oauth, the api and consumer should share the same address. to bad :(

Comment: you could add some hosts to your /etc/hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\etc\hosts or something like this on windows) and set some proxies in your apache2 config. so u can have api.*.dev and *.dev to check if it is working